# how to make union of same table in sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my sql which shows below data
I have to keep data below to each other as per dpr date, bid date as category and show their dates. Basically union of the same table.

```
Region  Market  Project PS ID   Site Name       dpr date    bid date
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 134027  ROWLAND_SPRINGS 2/14/2017   2/28/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 165455  EGG AND BUTTER  2/22/2017   2/28/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 134359  DOLDSONVILLE    2/22/2017   2/28/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 121528  EASTABOGA       2/22/2017   2/28/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 133398  PATRICK_MILL    2/22/2017   3/6/2017
```

I have to write a query which shows data in below format

```
Region  Market  Project PS ID   Site Name       Categoty     date
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 134027  ROWLAND_SPRINGS dpr date    2/14/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 165455  EGG AND BUTTER  dpr date    2/22/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 134359  DOLDSONVILLE    dpr date    2/22/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 121528  EASTABOGA       dpr date    2/22/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 133398  PATRICK_MILL    dpr date    2/22/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 134027  ROWLAND_SPRINGS Bid date    2/28/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 165455  EGG AND BUTTER  Bid date    2/28/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 134359  DOLDSONVILLE    Bid date    2/28/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 121528  EASTABOGA       Bid datn    2/28/2017
East    GAAL    DTS_AWS 133398  PATRICK_MILL    Bid date    3/6/2017
```

Comment: So "data in below format" is impossible to anyone here to GUESS how to do that without knowing your tables schema. There are new columns there, where they came from, how they are related with the first table? Also, this is not a free code service, try yourself something first then post here your attempt so we can see your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is absolutely unclear and table schema seem weird or wrong. 
But just a guess of how to achieve your expected result:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc6b2/3

```
SELECT 
  Region,  
  Market,  
  Project, 
  PS_ID,   
  Site_Name, 
  'dpr date' category,
  dpr
FROM t1
UNION
SELECT 
  Region,  
  Market,  
  Project, 
  PS_ID,   
  Site_Name, 
  'Bid date' category,
  bid
FROM t1;
```

Comment: I did the same thing